# Parsing a array through a request.get and setting each result into a var | Python

Tags: python, arrays

So, I have a string array and need to parse it through a link and save it EACH result from the webpage(its just raw text).

I have tried doing:

```
game1 = requests.get(f"http://localhost:8080/auth/{gameid}/{lol[0]}")
```

- Only issue is what if there is more than 1 in the array but if I have another one like this:

```
game2 = requests.get(f"http://localhost:8080/auth/{gameid}/{lol[1]}")
```

- Which brings the issue of what if there is only one and not 2 which would cause a "out of range" error.
  I basically wanna save each array result from the link to seperate variables like

```
game2
game3
etc
```

But only set the amount of variables that are actually needed from the array.

Is there anyway around this?

- Thank you for reading.

Comment: Your question isn’t very clear - maybe you want to use a list for the value retrieved using `requests.get()`? Look up list in the Python documentation and also look up built-in list methods like `append()` to add a new value to the list.

Comment: I know, my english is not the best.. I have a string array and want to parse them through a link and then save each request result to a seperate variable for each one.

Comment: You use a list so you don’t have to use a variable names - and as you say you don’t know how many results there will be then a list sounds like the perfect solution.